# ERESOLVE could not resolve on build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, deployment

I am trying to deploy a React Native project, however when using React Native 18.0.0 - I get the following errors:

[image]

**Solutions Tried**

1. removing node_modules and package.json.lock and downgrading react to 17.0.2 - I then get:

[image]

2. npm install --legacy-peer-deps
3. npm i web-vitals --save-dev
4. npm config set legacy-peer-deps

Nothing works.

Is successful deployment even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check your package.json probably you have the wrong version or react in dependencies. The right version for RN 0.69.6 is `"react": "18.0.0"`

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain myself properly. React 18.0.0 doesn't work because React Testing Library doesn't work with React 18.0.0 - When downgrading to 17.0.2 to solve this problem, React Native doesn't work, so I'm stuck.

Comment: have you tried this version of testing library with React 18 support https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/releases/tag/v13.0.0

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. however I decided that because I don't need the tests in production mode, I deleted all the react-testing-library dependencies from package.json, I then upgraded React to 18.0.0. The build then succeeded. Maybe if I have some spare time I could try the release you suggested at a later point.